# The ViewData item that has the key 'MY KEY' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to populate a dropdown list from a database mapped with Linq-2-SQL, using ASP.NET MVC 2, and keep getting this error.

I am so confused because I am declaring a variable of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` on the second line, but the error makes me think this is not the case. I feel like this should be very simple, but I am struggling. Any help is appreciated.

Here are the interesting bits of my controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var db = new DB();
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> basetypes = db.Basetypes.Select(
        b => new SelectListItem { Value = b.basetype, Text = b.basetype });
    ViewData["basetype"] = basetypes;
    return View();
}
```

And here are the interesting bits of my view:

```
<div class="editor-label">
   <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.basetype) %>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
   <%: Html.DropDownList("basetype") %>
   <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.basetype) %>
</div>
```

Here is the POST action when submitting the Form

```
// POST: /Meals/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Meal meal)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            var db = new DB();
            db.Meals.InsertOnSubmit(meal);
            db.SubmitChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View(meal);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return View(meal);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The dropdown list appears in the view just fine. It populates from the database as it should, but it's when I post the form that I get these errors.

Comment: Summary of accepted answer: Make sure you populate the list in both the get and post actions of your controller.  It's easy to forget to do this, and then end up wasting time searching for a more complicated bug.

Answer (score 211, accepted):

I had same problem, and finally I got the answer...

The problem is that in the POST action, after submitting the form, the ModelState is not valid, or it's catching an error in try/catch, so the View is returned. But this time the View has not the `ViewData["basetype"]` correctly set.

You need to populate it again, probably with the same code used before, so repeat this:

```
var db = new DB();
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> basetypes = db.Basetypes.Select(
    b => new SelectListItem { Value = b.basetype, Text = b.basetype });
ViewData["basetype"] = basetypes;
```

before the `return View(meal)` in the `[HttpPost]` method.

exactly this will solve your problem:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Meal meal)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            var db = new DB();
            db.Meals.InsertOnSubmit(meal);
            db.SubmitChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            var db = new DB();
            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> basetypes = db.Basetypes.Select(
               b => new SelectListItem { Value = b.basetype, Text = b.basetype });
            ViewData["basetype"] = basetypes;
            return View(meal);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var db = new DB();
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> basetypes = db.Basetypes.Select(
            b => new SelectListItem { Value = b.basetype, Text = b.basetype });
        ViewData["basetype"] = basetypes;
        return View(meal);
    }
}
```

I know this question is very old, but I came here today with the same problem, so other could come here later...

Comment: +1 for "populate it again"...I have a fairly robust system in place for composing my view models, but I had completely forgotten to call it. Thus, the property wasn't populated and I received this (rather ambiguous) message no matter what I tried.

Comment: if you get this BEFORE a post, it's because there is nothing in the SelectList, just found that one.

Comment: +1 Because I was setting my ViewBag in the Index method when I was really calling an Html.Action to another Action Method!!

Comment: Thanks.  It would be nice if it were just preserved but I suppose that wouldn't be the MVC "way."

Comment: if the model is getting is invalidated then i come the data submitted by the user will be saved in the db? i am also facing same problem. i am a newbie. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Peto , i have a model for a VIEW(page) that contains IList<SelectListItem>  , on post the List<SelectListItem> returns null .

so even for model i need to prepare again a List<SelectListItem> when i want to return to same view from Post Action .

Comment: thank you. even I think if I had spent hours, it wouldn't come to my mind that data is required to be populated again; especially the message is refering to the selected value, not to the populated list variable

Answer (score 88):

You will receive this error if the SelectList is null.

Comment: Yep, this is a common error/oversight when you set up the SelectList on a GET then postback to a POST action (obviously) that has an `ModelState.IsValid==false` so you return the model `return View(model)`  but don't repopulate your SelectList source before returning from the POST. Since there's no ViewState ala WebForms, there's no source for the `@Html.DropDown` helper to rebuild the select with. You have to populate that source list EVERY time you return the view to the client not just on the GET.

Comment: yep this was my issue. Forgot to populate the selectList on the get call.  Very misleading error.  Great post.

Answer (score 3):

I've just come across this issue and this article helped me through it - http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2010/01/18/drop-down-lists-and-asp-net-mvc.aspx

The most likely cause it that your collection is repopulated after the po

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, if you are using razor, try to change type of selectlist item from List to IEnumerable.

From

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.id, ViewBag.SomeList as List<SelectListItem>)
```

To

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.id, ViewBag.SomeList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the collection as an item in ViewData dictionary and trying to retreive it as property on the model. A simple fix would be to reference it the same way as you set it:

```
    <%var basetype = ViewData["basetype"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>;%>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.Label("basetype") %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.DropDownList("basetype", basetype) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessage("basetype") %>
    </div>
```

Alternatively, the below code uses a strongly typed view:

```
public class ViewModel {
   //Model properties
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> basetype {get;set;}
}

public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var db = new DB();
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> basetypes = db.Basetypes.Select(b => new SelectListItem { Value = b.basetype, Text = b.basetype });
        return View(new ViewModel { basetype=basetypes });
    }
```

Then, in your strongly typed view:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.basetype) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.basetype) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.basetype) %>
    </div>
```

Comment: I've tried using the code in your "simple fix" example, and got the same error. I should have mentioned that the dropdown list populates in the View ok, but I get this error when I submit the form.

Comment: Can you post the code for the Controller Action that handles the form submission?

Comment: Sure, I'll add it to the original post. Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a string for the name of your dropdown list as the first parameter, and get the item out of your viewdata:

```
 <%= Html.DropDownList("SomeDropdownName", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["basetype"]) %>
```

Here is also an extension method you can use so the dropdown list is set up in a similar style to how you have done your other controls:

```
        public static string DropDownList<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, string optionLabel)
        where TModel : class
    {
        string inputName = ExpressionHelper.GetInputName(expression);
        return htmlHelper.DropDownList(inputName, selectList, optionLabel);
    }
```

For example

```
<%= Html.DropDownList(x => x.BaseType, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["basetype"], "")%>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Html.DropDownList()` method - same error may occur, if your ViewData/Viewbag item not set, as @Peto answered.

But it may be not set in case of controller set item correctly, but in main view you use partial viw call with new ViewDataDictionary values.

if you have `@Html.Partial("Partianame", Model,new ViewDataDictionary() { /* ... */ })` then your partial view will not see `ViewData` and `ViewBag` data, remove `new ViewDataDictionary()` parameter

Answer (score 0):

To future readers,

I came across with the problem today and couldn´t fix it. It turned to be really simple after all. I was working with a table + view. When I updated the table (added a few colums) I forgot to update (drop and recreate) the view, which caused the problem for me. 
Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error today and my solution is to make model "valid".

In my case, after user submit by clicking "save", I got model state: invalid if user key-in "0", but model state will be valid if user key-in "0.0".

So I override "IsValid" method to return true even user key-in "0".

Hope it helps.