# MVC 3 Html.DropDownList error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have that error

```
The ViewData item that has the key 'BookAttributesDDL' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.
```

in that code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("BookAttributesDDL", Model.BookAttributes_Items)
```

but the `Model.BookAttributes_Items` is type of the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` ! What's wrong ?

The `ViewData.Keys` property from the Immediate Window:

```
ViewData.Keys
Count = 2
    [0]: "FCoookie"
    [1]: "Title"
```

Comment: do you have an entry in `ViewData` that has the key `BookAttributesDDL`? if so, change the name of that key in `ViewData` as it conflicts with the first parameter in the `DropDownList` method.

Comment: I've checked that already, I don't have the `BookAttributesDDL` key in my `ViewData`

Comment: mind posting the relevant code, particularly the ViewModel `class`

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid dynamic variables like ViewBag and ViewData. It will make your code unreadable and painful to maintain in future as it grows. ViewBag is like Magic strings !

Switch to the **ViewModel** approach.

Example, If you are creating a View to Create a Book, Create a `Viewmodel` (*it is just a plain Class*) for that like this

```
public class BookViewModel
{
  public int BookId { set;get;}
  public string BookName {set;get;}
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Attributes{ get; set; }
  public int SelectedAttribute{ get; set; }

}
```

Now in your `GET` Action, Simply create an object of this class, Set the `BookAttribbutes` proeprties to your Dropdown items and pass this ViewModel object to the View

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  BookViewModel vm=new BookViewModel();
  //The below code is hardcoded for demo. you mat replace with DB data.
  vm.Attributes=new[]
  {
    new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "F Cookie" },
    new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Title" },
  }
  return View(vm);
}
```

Now in We will make our view strongly typed to this ViewModel class

```
@model BookViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
 @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.BookName)
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedAttribute, 
      new SelectList(Model.Attributes, "Value", "Text"), "Select Attribute")

 <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Now you will get the Selected Dropdown value and the textbox value in your HttpPost action by accessing the corresponding properties of your ViewModel

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(BookViewModel model)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  { 
    //check for model.BookName / model.SelectedAttribute
  }
  //validation failed.TO DO : reload dropdown here
  return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fully agree with View Model approach response to you (and its me who selected it as useful).
However, if you don't want to switch, but remain as is I bet your answer lays in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393521/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-my-key-is-of-type-system-string-but-must).

Hope this help you.