# Persisting Dropdown information when ModelState is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm having some issues with my DropDownLists, because when I post the information and my Model is not valid it comes back "empty" to the page triggering an error exactly like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393521/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-my-key-is-of-type-system-string-but-must).

I've used the solution proposed there and it fixed my problem. Anyway, I wanted to avoid querying the database every time my ModelState is not valid and I came with this approach. I would like to know if it is valid or if there are better ways to do it now, considering that instead of MVC2 (which was the MVC version from the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393521/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-my-key-is-of-type-system-string-but-must)) I'm now using MVC 5, maybe they added something new to tackle this.

What I've done was to use the TempData to persist the information when my model is not valid.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Project")]
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Projects { get; set; }

    //Other fields
}
```

Now my Create() Action (that populates Projects)

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewModel vmodel = new ViewModel();
    vmodel.Projects = db.GetProjects(User.Identity.Name).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Description, Value = x.Id }).ToList();
    TempData["Projects"] = vmodel.Projects;

    return View(vmodel);
}
```

And my post would be like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(ViewModel vmodel)
{
    //Clear TempData (in theory will clear my tempdata when read, so if this controller redirects to another action my tempdata will be clear)
    List<SelectListItem> projects = (TempData["Projects"] as List<SelectListItem>);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //...
    }

    //If it got here it's going back to the screen.
    //Repopulate the TempData (allowing it to exist one more trip)
    TempData["Projects"] = projects;
    vmodel.Projects = projects

    return View(atendimento);
}
```

Is this approach a good one? Is there a better way to achieve that without querying the database every single time?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tested TempData with this approach? I though TempData only survived through the same HTTP request, meaning it should die when the page loads, and not be available on the postback.

Comment: Yep, I just did it before posting here. It works because I'm accessing the ViewModel to populate the DropDownList instead of the TempData. This way it is only accessed back on the controller. If there's an error in the controller I simply repopulate the TempData granting it another trip to the screen and back (since it's not read there)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to use `TempData` at all as you have a property in your view model to hold the dropdown items.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewModel vmodel = new ViewModel();
    vmodel.Projects = GetProjects(); 
    return View(vmodel);
}
private List<SelectListItem> GetProjects()
{
     return db.GetProjects(User.Identity.Name)
                 .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Description,
                                                   Value = x.Id }).ToList();   
}
```

And in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(s=>s.ProjectID,Model.Projects)
```

And in your HttpPost action, If ModelState is not valid, Reload the `Projects` collection again (**because http is stateless**)

```
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
  // to do :Save and redirect
}
model.Projects = GetProjects(); 
return View(model);
```

You may cache the `Projects` so that you do not need to hit the database every time, if you are too much worried about performance.

Comment: I'm using the view exactly like that, what I wanted to avoid is to reload the projects every single time the model is incorrect from the database, specially because my information is User sensitive and it is a pretty big database.

Comment: @RafaelMerlin That is y i mentioned you may cache it as needed. check this post http://stevescodingblog.co.uk/net4-caching-with-mvc/

Comment: This example shows standard, best practice usage. Unless in your specific example the database is having performance issues, then I would stick to this kind of model. The question is, how often are the users going to incorrectly fill out the form. Caching has it's own performance overhead (though it is on the webserver side).

Comment: Remember that `TempData` use `Session` as the back store. Imagine you have 1000+ clients doing this and your are heating up your server with session data !

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really like the article you added here as well.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wouldn't worry about querying the database each time for this kind of operation.

What if projects are added/deleted?  This could be the reason the save failed (selected project deleted) and the user would never realise it.

I usually write a method to populate all of my view model's `SelectListItem`s and then use this in my `Get` and in my `Post` if the validation fails.

Comment: I used this just for an example, I'm as a matter of fact calling a very heavy stored procedure to achieve the information I need. I'm not working only with projects, I have at least 10 different dropdowns in my screen and most of them have less than 20 items each, so I thought that it would be better to keep the information instead of getting it again from the Db.

Comment: Is it possible that one of the items that the user has selected could have been deleted while they are filling in the form?  This could potentially be seen as a validation error depending on how you implement your validation.  If this is likely to happen, keeping the same items would be wrong.