# MVC dropdownlist httppost, need to lookup

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form which has a dropdownlist in it, which I'm able to populate and retrieve when users are posting the form. I wanted to know if there is another way to handle this, so if the form posts and there is an error I do not have to look up the data again to populate the dropdown, as that is what I'm doing now.

```
public ActionResult Identity(int id)
{
    var profile =.....
    profile.gender = _myservice.GetGenders();
    return View(profile);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Identity(int id, Profile profile)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // save data and redirect
        ....
    }
    // if error, rebuild dropdown and send back to user
    var profile =.....
    profile.gender = _myservice.GetGenders();
    return View(profile);
}
```

Comment: Caching and TempData are possibilities. Trade-offs are discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22406452/persisting-dropdown-information-when-modelstate-is-not-valid

Comment: @SteveGreene ok looks like i'll leave it, from those posts looks like querying shouldn't be a big deal, after all my dropdowns are small

Answer (score 0):

If the dropdownlist is the same for all users then use the application cache. Otherwise, store the collection in the user's session cache. Either way, the mechanics are basically the same.

```
public IList<Gender> GetGenders()
{
    const string cacheKey = "MyApp_GendersKey";
    if (HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get(cacheKey) == null)
    {
        lock (HttpContext.Current.Cache)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(
                cacheKey,
                 _myservice.GetGenders(),
                null,
                DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
                System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration
                );
        }
    }
    return (List<Gender>)HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get(cacheKey);
}
```