# The ViewData item that has the key 'ShelfId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, viewbag, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

### Problem

I use the following code very similarily somewhere else in my application, but it is not working. I am completely stumped.

```
The ViewData item that has the key 'ShelfId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'
```

This is thrown during the post method. My model state is invalid.

### Code

**Models**

**Shelf**

```
public class Shelf 
{
      [Key]
      public int ShelfId 

      [Display(Name = "Shelf Id")]
      [Required]
      public string ShelfName

      public virtual List<Book> Books {get; set;}

}
```

**Book**

```
public class Book 
{
      public int BookId 

      [Required]
      [StrengthLength(160, MinimumLength = 8)]
      public string BookName

      public int ShelfId

      public Shelf shelf {get; set;}


}
```

**Controller**

```
// GET: Units/Create
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
        {


            var shelves = await _db.Shelves.OrderBy(q => q.Name).ToListAsync();
            ViewBag.SelectedShelves = new SelectList(shelves, "ShelfId", "Name");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Units/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Book book)
        {
            book.CreatedBy = User.Identity.GetUserName();
            book.Created = DateTime.UtcNow;
            book.UpdatedBy = User.Identity.GetUserName();
            book.Updated = DateTime.UtcNow;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Units.Add(unit);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(book);
        }
```

### view

```
@model AgentInventory.Models.Book

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Create Unit</title>
</head>
<body>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal well bs-component" style="margin-top:20px">
        <h4>Unit</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="control-label col-md-2">Room</div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ShelfId, (SelectList)ViewBag.SelectedShelves, "All", new { @class = "form-control" })
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BookName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BookName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

### Attempts

I tried:

- Adding `@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.ShelfId)` in the create view, but that didn't work.
- I have looked at similar issues on stackoverflow, but none of the fixes worked for me. (IE - hiddenfor, different kinds of selectlists)

Since I am new to MVC framework, I would be grateful for any assistance. I don't understand why this code works for two other kinds of models (Building and room), but not my current two models? It's weird.

PS - Is there a way to do this easily without using viewbag as well?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393521/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-my-key-is-of-type-system-string-but-must

Comment: @CodeCaster When I do that it returns me straight back to the Create view with no errors. I think I need to take a closer look at the debugger for the invalid state model. I suspect something is screwed up there and hopefully will reveal itself.

Comment: If `ModelState` is invalid, you return the view, but do not reassign the `SelectList` so its null, hence the error.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not convinced yet. I only return the "create view" after I instantiate the viewbag object from the get method before the return view in the post method. Otherwise, if I don't have that there, it explodes when it tries to validate the model and returns the original error message I gave above.

Comment: Yes because the `SelectList` is `null` when you return the view. You need to use `ViewBag.SelectedShelves = new SelectList(shelves, "ShelfId", "Name");` in the POST method when you return the view.

Comment: var shelves = await db.Shelves.OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToListAsync();
            ViewBag.SelectedShelves = new SelectList(shelves, "BookId", "Name");

Comment: @StephenMuecke The code I have in my comment above is what I put in the POST method when I return the view. When I do that, I get no error messages, just the create view. So this technique does not help me in MVC6, I think. I'm going through the debugger right now as we speak. Pretty deep inside. I will share what I find.

Comment: What do you mean, you get the create view? That's what you are supposed to get. If `ModelState` is invalid, it returns the view so the user can correct the errors. What are you expecting to happen

Comment: @StephenMuecke Fair enough. I get what you mean now. At first,  I was lead to believe by the first link above that I would get a more meaningful  error. I only have two fields in the create view. The book name and what shelf I am on. I suspect that my application has a "null" field value in either shelf model or book model (but is required) and my create post method is having an error.

Comment: Well your `Book` model obviously has other properties such as `CreatedBy` which you have not shown. No doubt some of those have validation attributes hence `ModelState` is invalid. You really need to start using view models to represent what you want to display/edit.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, I thought this was something simple and it turned out to be rather in depth. I am coding up a complete sample application of what I got and will post on github and here. Give me some time. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that in the POST method when you return the view, the value of `ViewBag.SelectedShelves` is null because you have not set it (as you did in the get method. I recommend you refactor this in a private method that can be called from both the GET and POST methods

```
private void ConfigureViewModel(Book book)
{
  var shelves = await _db.Shelves.OrderBy(q => q.Name).ToListAsync();
  // Better to have a view model with a property for the SelectList
  ViewBag.SelectedShelves = new SelectList(shelves, "ShelfId", "Name");
}
```

then in the controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
{
  // Always better to initialize a new object and pass to the view
  Book model = new Book();
  ConfigureViewModel(model)
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Book book)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ConfigureViewModel(book)
    return View(book);
  }
  // No point setting these if the model is invalid
  book.CreatedBy = User.Identity.GetUserName();
  book.Created = DateTime.UtcNow;
  book.UpdatedBy = User.Identity.GetUserName();
  book.Updated = DateTime.UtcNow;
  // Save and redirect
  db.Units.Add(unit);
  await db.SaveChangesAsync();
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Note your `Book` class contains only fields, not properties (no `{ get; set; }`) so no properties will be set and the model will always be invalid because `BookName` has `Required` and `StringLength` attributes.

Also you have not shown all the properties in your model (for example you have `CreatedBy`, `Created` etc. and its likely that `ModelState` will also be invalid because you only generate controls for only a few properties. If any other properties contain validation attributes, then `ModelState` will be invalid. To handle this you need to create a view model containing only the properties you want to display edit.

```
public class BookVM
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  [Required]
  [StrengthLength(160, MinimumLength = 8)]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int SelectedShelf { get; set; }
  public SelectList ShelfList { get; set; }
}
```

Then modify the private method to assign the `SelectList` to the view model (not `ViewBag`, and in the controller methods, pass a new instance of `BookVM` to the view, and post back to

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(BookVM model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ConfigureViewModel(model)
    return View(model);
  }
  // Initialize a new Book and set the properties from the view model
}
```

Comment: This answer is a work of art. I cannot prop this answer enough. Also, you explanation of why the error occurs is fantastic.